# Recursive java method for strings

Tags: java, string, recursion

So im stuck on this recursive java method so I am are to write a recursion that gets a string and two characters and returns the substring that is enclosed in two given characters. You can assume that the given string includes only one instance of each enclosing characters.
For example, if the input string is “Hello (there] how are you?” and the first enclosing character is '(' and the second is ']', it should return “there”

```java
public static String getSubstring(String str, char open, char close) {
  if(str.length() < 2) {
    return "";
  } else {
    if (str.length()>= 2 && str.charAt(0) == open && str.charAt(1) == close){
      return "";
    }
  }
  return getSubstring(str.substring(1), open, close);
}
```

I have this but its not working I think I need to create a whole new string that goes through the length of the substring I also have something like this

```java
public static String getSubstring(String str, char open, char close) {
  int openIndex = str.indexOf(open);
  int closeIndex = str.indexOf(close);
  
  if(str.length() < 2) {
    return "";
  } 

  String newString = newString + str.substring(openIndex, openIndex + 1) ;
}
```

but I dont know where to go from here

Comment: `str.charAt(0) == open && str.charAt(1) == close` will only ever be true if you have nothing in between those enclosing characters. Sit down with a bit of pen and paper, and draw out each iteration instead of looking at your code: start with `"hello (there] sir"` and move up one character at a time: at what point do you hit an opener? And where is the closer when that happens? Do you keep going? If so, until when?

Comment: hmm I've tried this basically I expect my code to stop the iteration once I reach the end character so must I compare every character I am going to add to the string with the last character how would I go about this??

Comment: Pretty much like that: you check if the first character is the closing character, and if it's not that character is part of your return value. If it is, you're done and you can stop recursing.

Comment: The problem as stated __does not make sense__ - nothing about the problem statement is eligible for any sort of recursive algorithm. A slight variation on the question at least makes sense ("A string is provided that is surrounded by __any amount of__ open/close pairs. Return the string with all the pairs removed"), i.e. given: `"(((((abc))))"`, `(`, `)` - return the value `"(abc"`.

Comment: We can bend over backwards and cook something up that's technically recursive but it wouldn't be sane by any reasonable definition. Perhaps go back to the source and check if you understood the task correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I have this but its not working I think I need to create a whole new string that goes through the length of the substring ..."*

Essentially, return *str* when either *open* or *close* is not found.
Otherwise, send the *substring* to the method.

```java
String getSubstring(String str, char open, char close) {
    if (str.length() < 2) return str;
    int i = str.indexOf(open), j = str.indexOf(close);
    if (Math.min(i, j) == -1) return str;
    return getSubstring(str.substring(i + 1, j), open, close);
}
```

Comment: thanks I've modified the code a bit because it was passing all but 1 of my test cases but this really helped

Comment: @ComputerScienceHelp, if it helped, you might consider marking the answer as accepted.